# How to hide nearest<p> tag which are dynamically generated and not having any class or id using jquery

Tags: jquery, hide, siblings, closest

How to hide nearest `<p>` tag which are dynamically generated and not having any class or id using jquery

I want to hide `<p>` tag of city only

```
<div>
<input type="text" name="state" id="state">
<p>This is required filed</p>
</div>

<div>
<input type="text" name="city" id="city">
<p>This is required filed</p>
</div>
```

Solution:

```
$("#state").siblings('p:first').hide();

Output:
<div>
<input type="text" name="state" id="state">
<p>This is required filed</p>
</div>

<div>
<input type="text" name="city" id="city">
</div>

This code is working for me.
I am using this code in PHP.
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve, could you please elaborate what your problem is. Make sure you include all code

Comment: [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)?

Comment: Your question is not clear, kindly explain a bit more that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

To hide the p following the city input, just use the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) "+" and the [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

```js
$("[name=city] + p").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<input type="text" name="state" id="state">
<p>This is required filed</p>
</div>

<div>
<input type="text" name="city" id="city">
<p>This is required filed</p>
</div>
```